# Can i add ballon toolbar in tinymce react editor?

Tags: tinymce

Can i add balloon editor, .i.e a toolbar should appear when i select a text. Can this be done for react version, because in the documentation there is written that it produces a basic version of tinymce editor.

I just want to know the answer of above question